# php parse/syntax error help

Tags: php, redirect, syntax-error

I keep getting a

```
 "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in /home/jobkill/public_html/process.php on line 8"
```

when processing inputs from a page that redirects here. I dont know what to fix,

Here's the code:

```
<?
$aff = $_GET['aff'] ;
$click_id = $_GET['click_id'] ;
$zipcode = @$_GET['zip'];
$state = @$_GET['custom_state'];
$subid = $_GET['subid'] ;
$urls = array(
“http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?

cdb=23&zip=<?print $zipcode?>”,
“http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?

cdb=80&zip=<?print $zipcode?>”,
“http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?

cdb=46&zip=<?print $zipcode?>”,
“http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?

cdb=37&zip=<?print $zipcode?>”,
“http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?

cdb=55&zip=<?print $zipcode?>”,
“http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?

cdb=71&zip=<?print $zipcode?>”);

$url = $urls[array_rand($urls)];

echo “<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=3; url='$url'>”;

?>
<html>
<HEAD>
<LINK href="./index_files/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<STYLE>
#middlename
{
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
}
</STYLE>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="./index_files/scripts.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" 

src="./index_files/functions.js"></SCRIPT>

<script language="JavaScript" 

src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
</HEAD><BODY>

<DIV id="form_complete">

<!-- OPEN MAIN TABLE -->
<TABLE width="100%" height="850" border="0" align="center" 

cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tablebg2">
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD valign="top" align="center">


  <!-- OPEN PLACEMENT TABLE -->
  <table width="1010" height="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" 

cellpadding="0">

    <tr><td height="220" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="51%"><div align="center"><img 

src="index_files/blank.gif" border="0" width="425" height="344" 

/></div></td>
      <td 

width="10%">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp

;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td

>
      <td width="39%" align="left">


    &nbsp;
    <br /><br /><br />
    <div id="super-container0">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;font-

size:24px;color:#898;">Now Searching...</span><br /><span 

style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;font-size:32px;"><script 

language="Javascript">document.write(geoip_city());</script>, <script 

language="Javascript">document.write(geoip_region());</script></span>
      <!-- <h2>for <span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold">30-

34</span> Year Old <span style="color:#000000;font-

weight:bold">Male</span> Drivers</h2> -->
      <div id="block"></div>
      <div id="progress-bar"><img src="index_files/progress.gif"></div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </DIV>






    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="350" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td colspan="3">
    <DIV class="Privacy" style="width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;">
      <P style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-

size:11px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">All personal information and 

email addresses are kept confidential. By           

submitting your expression of interest you are consenting to receive 

telephone calls from our participating partners even if you have been 

previously listed on a state or federal Do-Not-Call List.
    </P><P style="width: 1000px; text-align: center; margin-top: 0px; 

padding-top: 0px;"><A href="#" onclick="MM_openBrWindow

(&#39;privacy.htm&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=

400&#39;)" target="_blank" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-

serif; font-size:10px; color:#03C">Privacy Policy</A></P>
</DIV></td>
  </tr>
</table> <!-- CLOSE PLACEMENT TABLE -->
</TD></TR></TABLE>  <!-- CLOSE MAIN TABLE -->



<DIV id="processing" style="display:none">
<br /><br /><br /><br />
<CENTER><img src="./index_files/logo2.gif" /><br /><br />
<H2>Searching for a specialist now ...<BR>Thank you for giving us an 

opportunity to assist you today.</H2><STRONG>(Please do not Refresh 

page as that will result in an error in the system.)</STRONG><BR>

  <IMG src="./index_files/ajax-loader.gif" width="220" height="19" 

alt="Processing">
</CENTER>
</DIV>

</BODY></html>
```

Comment: Please add the code of line 8 as text to your question (not a screenshot).

Comment: Usually better if you post the code, not an image of it

Comment: When pasting code you should indent it with at least 4 spaces. Read more.. [How do i format my code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074)

Comment: paste your code here please. hilight the code and apply the code tool from the tool box

Comment: is `site` in the `What does it mean when the site keeps saying..` means stackoverflow?

Comment: you can add your code with the `{}` block you can find in the toolbar when you create or edit a post. Select your text and then click on the button and you will see the format on the preview

Comment: This should be on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @MithunP meta.SO is intended for questions about this system, not code review.

Comment: @Lekensteyn i was referring to http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6503458/4

Comment: @MithunP: oh, I thought it was you who voted for moving this question to meta.SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
added whole code, tested and working

replace `<?print $zipcode?`> with `$zipcode`

i.e. `“http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?cdb=23&zip=<?print $zipcode?>”,`
into `“http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?cdb=23&zip=$zipcode”,`

and replace quotation marks (`“”`) to normal ones (`""`)

basically your code should look like this:

```
<?php
$aff = $_GET['aff'] ;
$click_id = $_GET['click_id'] ;
$zipcode = @$_GET['zip'];
$state = @$_GET['custom_state'];
$subid = $_GET['subid'] ;
$urls = array(
"http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?cdb=23&zip=$zipcode",
"http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?cdb=80&zip=$zipcode",
"http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?cdb=46&zip=$zipcode",
"http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?cdb=37&zip=$zipcode",
"http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?cdb=55&zip=$zipcode",
"http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?cdb=71&zip=$zipcode");

$url = $urls[array_rand($urls)];
?>
<html>
<HEAD>
<LINK href="./index_files/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<STYLE>
#middlename
{
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
}
</STYLE>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="./index_files/scripts.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" 

src="./index_files/functions.js"></SCRIPT>

<script language="JavaScript" 

src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=<?php echo $url; ?>"> 
</HEAD><BODY>

<DIV id="form_complete">

<!-- OPEN MAIN TABLE -->
<TABLE width="100%" height="850" border="0" align="center" 

cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tablebg2">
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD valign="top" align="center">


  <!-- OPEN PLACEMENT TABLE -->
  <table width="1010" height="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" 

cellpadding="0">

    <tr><td height="220" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="51%"><div align="center"><img 

src="index_files/blank.gif" border="0" width="425" height="344" 

/></div></td>
      <td 

width="10%">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp

;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td

>
      <td width="39%" align="left">


    &nbsp;
    <br /><br /><br />
    <div id="super-container0">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;font-

size:24px;color:#898;">Now Searching...</span><br /><span 

style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;font-size:32px;"><script 

language="Javascript">document.write(geoip_city());</script>, <script 

language="Javascript">document.write(geoip_region());</script></span>
      <!-- <h2>for <span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold">30-

34</span> Year Old <span style="color:#000000;font-

weight:bold">Male</span> Drivers</h2> -->
      <div id="block"></div>
      <div id="progress-bar"><img src="index_files/progress.gif"></div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </DIV>






    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="350" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td colspan="3">
    <DIV class="Privacy" style="width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;">
      <P style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-

size:11px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">All personal information and 

email addresses are kept confidential. By           

submitting your expression of interest you are consenting to receive 

telephone calls from our participating partners even if you have been 

previously listed on a state or federal Do-Not-Call List.
    </P><P style="width: 1000px; text-align: center; margin-top: 0px; 

padding-top: 0px;"><A href="#" onclick="MM_openBrWindow

(&#39;privacy.htm&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=

400&#39;)" target="_blank" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-

serif; font-size:10px; color:#03C">Privacy Policy</A></P>
</DIV></td>
  </tr>
</table> <!-- CLOSE PLACEMENT TABLE -->
</TD></TR></TABLE>  <!-- CLOSE MAIN TABLE -->



<DIV id="processing" style="display:none">
<br /><br /><br /><br />
<CENTER><img src="./index_files/logo2.gif" /><br /><br />
<H2>Searching for a specialist now ...<BR>Thank you for giving us an 

opportunity to assist you today.</H2><STRONG>(Please do not Refresh 

page as that will result in an error in the system.)</STRONG><BR>

  <IMG src="./index_files/ajax-loader.gif" width="220" height="19" 

alt="Processing">
</CENTER>
</DIV>

</BODY></html>
```

Comment: @Inori: Yeah that was one point I ran over as well. However it's not creating the syntax error ;)

Comment: @Inori: I thought that's an error the OP did when copy and pasting her/his code, but yeah, if not, this will never work. And that looks like that is line 8 ;)

Comment: @hakre: well I tried the code with normal quotation marks and it started working

Comment: @Inori: And I tried it with the wrong quotes and I get that exact error message ;)

Comment: @lnori like you said it started working but it doesnt redirect to the destination page specified in the php code. what other error is in the code?

Comment: @user818709 I'm assuming because the meta tag is printed before every other html tag. Check my post for updated code that should work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your code are the quotes.

This character:

```
“
```

Is not recognised as a quotation in PHP, you need to use

```
'
```

Or

```
"
```

Here is the updated code

```
<?
$aff = $_GET['aff'] ;
$click_id = $_GET['click_id'] ;
$subid = $_GET['subid'];

$zipcode = '';
if (isset($_GET['zip']) {
    $zipcode = $_GET['zip'];
}

$state = '';
if (isset($_GET['custom_state']) {
    $state = $_GET['custom_state'];
}

$urls = array(
    'http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?cdb=23&zip=' . $zipcode,
    'http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?cdb=80&zip=' . $zipcode,
    'http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?cdb=46&zip=' . $zipcode,
    'http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?cdb=37&zip=' . $zipcode,
    'http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?cdb=55&zip=' . $zipcode,
    'http://consumerheadlinesdaily.com/debt/direct_2de89f.php?cdb=71&zip=' . $zipcode);

$url = $urls[array_rand($urls)];
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content=3; url='<? echo $url ?>'>
        <link href="./index_files/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style>
             #middlename
            {
                display:none;
                visibility:hidden;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./index_files/scripts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./index_files/functions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form_complete">
            <!-- OPEN MAIN TABLE -->
            <table width="100%" height="850" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tablebg2">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" align="center">
                            <!-- OPEN PLACEMENT TABLE -->
                            <table width="1010" height="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="220" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="51%">
                                        <div align="center">
                                            <img src="index_files/blank.gif" border="0" width="425" height="344" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="10%">
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="39%" align="left">
                                        &nbsp;<br /><br /><br />
                                        <div id="super-container0">
                                            <div id="wrapper">
                                                <span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;font-size:24px;color:#898;">Now Searching...</span><br />
                                                <span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;font-size:32px;">
                                                <script type="text/javascript">document.write(geoip_city());</script>,
                                                <script type="text/javascript">document.write(geoip_region());</script>
                                                </span>
                                                <!-- <h2>for <span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold">30-34</span> Year Old 
                                                <span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold">Male</span> Drivers</h2> -->
                                                <div id="block"></div>
                                                <div id="progress-bar"><img src="index_files/progress.gif"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="350" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3">
                                        <div class="Privacy" style="width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;">
                                            <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">All personal information and 
                                                email addresses are kept confidential. By submitting your expression of interest you are consenting to receive 
                                                telephone calls from our participating partners even if you have been 
                                                previously listed on a state or federal Do-Not-Call List.</p>
                                            <p style="width: 1000px; text-align: center; margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0px;"><a href="#" onclick="MM_openBrWindow(&#39;privacy.htm&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=400&#39;)" target="_blank" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#03C">Privacy Policy</a></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> <!-- CLOSE PLACEMENT TABLE -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>  <!-- CLOSE MAIN TABLE -->
        </div>
        <div id="processing" style="display:none">
            <br /><br /><br /><br />
            <center>
                <img src="./index_files/logo2.gif" /><br /><br />
                <H2>Searching for a specialist now ...<BR>Thank you for giving us an opportunity to assist you today.</h2>
                <strong>(Please do not Refresh page as that will result in an error in the system.)</strong><br>
                <img src="./index_files/ajax-loader.gif" width="220" height="19" alt="Processing">
            </center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have also...

- Fixed a couple of HTML errors, with missing closing tags or bad nesting
- Rather than using error suppression in PHP (@$_GET['mightnotexist']) I have performed an isset($_GET['mightnotexist']) check
- I have normalised the script tags

But I haven't...

- Removed the tables being used for layout
- Moved the inline styles into the stylesheet

Comment: ok thanks. the parse error stopped but it doesnt redirect to the destination page. its stuck on that page

Comment: Ah yes, your meta tag is in the wrong place... you could also use response headers to do this... example adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

replace "refresh" in your echo with \"refresh\"
and

```
<?print $zipcode?>
```

in array with 
    $zipcode

Comment: @user818709 another fix- check it out

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Checked your code and was able to reproduce your error. You're not using double quotes but some other obscure quotes that is not supported by PHP.

Proper double quotes are literally `"`. You can [learn about the details in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

You probably made an error while copy and pasting code from somewhere else in the internet that was changing code's quote's on the fly for styling and display reason.

Take care. The other problems in your code still stand (see other answers as well).

---

Try

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3; url='$url'\">";
```

instead of the similar but different line in your screenshot (it's no text, so I can't quote it and highlight the places you made errors in there, so sorry 'bout that).

This does not create the syntax error you're asking about however.

Comment: @user818709: Yeah, your code is full of problems, that's only one of them. Thought it's helpful as your question generally asked for help. So the less bugs you've in your code, the less you need to edit it, and the less you can introduce new errors ;)

Comment: @user818709: What exactly is line 8? I had asked you in comments below your question to post **that line 8** of your code that is giving the error.  Please add **that line 8** below your full code.

Comment: @user818709: Found your line 8 and the error, updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @hakre i made the changes and the parse error stopped but the page wont redirect to the url destination specified in the php code. what do you think is the error with the code?

Comment: @user: Inori has that. As written you should read the other answers carefully as well.