# php parse/syntax error - help

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php parse/syntax error help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503458/php-parse-syntax-error-help)

I keep getting a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in /home/jobkill/public_html/process.php on line 8" when processing inputs from a page that redirects here. I dont know what to fix.

Comment: for the record, to add code you just indent the code text by a minimum of 4 spaces each line.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use these backquotes, use

```
"
```

instead